# Why are physicists so worried about P-symmetry violations, while symmetry is already violated by conventions of intrinsic parity?

Tags: particle-physics

As it is well known, apart from +1 and -1 parities for particles and antiparticles, for intrinsic parity also defined "by convention" parity -1 for some symmetrical particles which are own antripartices. Such are, for example,  photon and neutral pion.

From the point of view of physical meaning that is strong equivalent to statement that photon and neutral pion are **antiparticles without particles**, which severely violates real symmetry of that particles by convention for intrinsic parity.

Then, (surprisingly) in calculations on particle reactions that already violated by convention P-symmetry appeared to be violated again (of course) and physicists are making from it a big deal.

Explain, if you please, why?

Comment: What interactions are you thinking about? What, exactly, do you construe parity violations as, and propose to understand about parity violation?

Comment: This is a question of entity of intrinsic parity concept and so, this is a question of consistency of P-symmetry considirations. One cannot have correct symmetry considerations basing on spoiled definition of what symmetry is.

Comment: does your physics background include this basic definition of parity? http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/parity.html

Comment: Yes, anna v, and that is what should be a partiry. And what was destroyed by assigning -1 partities for symmetrical particles which are own antiparticles by convention/definition.

Comment: It is not convention for composite of quarks particles, hadrons, click on the "parities of particles". the beautiful su(3) representations validate the basic rules http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/haddia.html#c1

Comment: The can see the statement "they have negative partity" for all scalar and vector mesons. Not only for particle which are own antiparticles, but also for particles and antiparticles. Is it consinstent to convension for fermions, which have parity +1 for particle and parity -1 for antiparticle?

Comment: Decay of neutral pion (which is own antiparticle) to 2 photons "violates P-symmetry"?

Comment: And does any real symmetry is violated it this case?

Comment: look at paragraph 3. here  https://www.imsc.res.in/~taushif/pdfs/Intrinsic%20parity%20of%20neutral%20pion.pdf . there is a relative angular momentum of the two photons that enters the game

Comment: Thank you very much for interesting link. Very interesting to read in detail how angular momentum (which can be taken into account separately) was mixed with parity concept.

Comment: And now I see the reason for inconsitensy of intrinsic parity concept and the reason why we see intrinsic parity from two differect incompatible poins of view. There are two incompatible concept inside of intrinsic parity concept.

Comment: First one, and initial, is naive concept of calculating matter-antimatter balance in the reactions. Let's call it "patricle/antiparticle parity". Conventions on +1 parity for proton, electron and negative muon and -1 parity for antiproton, positron and positive muon is a natural part of that concept.

Comment: In this naive "particle/antiparticle parity", if it were finished, negative pion would have parity +1 and posibive would have parity -1, and mesons would be classified as matter for negative and for as antimatter for positive (in opposite way to random current convention on matter for positive mesons)

Comment: Photon and neutral pion would not have  "particle/antiparticle parity", being not matter not antimatter, but symmetrical. But it would be possible to assign +1 parities for them, as +1 do not change result of parity calculation.

Comment: Alhough it would be naive concept, it would be useful, as it would help to classify mesons to particle / antiparticle / self after applying to reactons. May be it would also help to understand that solution does exist in which there is no violances of that  "particle/antiparticles parity" in reactions of beta decay.

Comment: Unfortunately, it was not finished. Intead, another one concept was mixed, to destroy whole concept of intrinsic parity. As one cannot have consistent concept, basing on incompatible to each other subconcepts.

Comment: Let's call this another parity concept "wavefuctions even/odd parity". In that concept both proton and antiproton would have same parity (probably, but not exactly  -1) . Single photon would probably have -1 parity. Probably (but not exactly), negative and positive pion would have -1 parity and neutral pion would have +1 parity. We do not know. As this "wavefuctions even/odd parity" was never created as concept in pure state.

Comment: Instead of two pure different concepts, we have some random hybrid of two incompatible concepts with unpredictable result of calculations. In psychology things like that were "multiple personality disorder". In programming things like that were some "undefined behavior"  errors. What is the name for this in physics? Misconception? Inconsistency of the concept?

Comment: Ultimate context here is C, P, T trinity of transformations. https://www.asc.ohio-state.edu/gan.1/teaching/winter10/Chapter6.pdf discusses P-parity which is usual reflection parity. There is also C-parity for neutral particles and G-parity which is 'reflection plus charge conjugation' for charged particles. Peculiarities of these two come from quantum manner of definition which requires objects which are unchanged by the transformation except for scalar factor - eigenvalue of the transformation - which then becomes the value of C- or G-parity.

Comment: Thank you very, Mitchell

Comment: But if instead of dπ- → nn reaction we will take  reaction corresponding antiparticles we will get +1 partity for π+ in such a manner? But bosons are postulated as particles which having same parity... Conventions obviously conflicts with parity operator. Two conflicting concepts inside one.