# Why does electron-positron annihilation conserve parity?

Tags: particle-physics, angular-momentum, antimatter, parity

I think I'm missing something quite basic here but consider the process:

$$ e^- + e^+ \rightarrow 2\gamma$$

Fermions have opposite parity to antifermions so the parity quantum number before the process is $P=-1 \times (-1)^L$ where $L$ is the relative orbital angular momentum, which should vanish in the zero momentum frame where the collision is head on. So we start with $P=-1$. The photons on the other hand have the same parity as each other so have parity $P=+1$ (after again noting that they must be heading in opposite directions to each other in the ZMF so have $L=0$).

I think my reasoning about the angular momentum must be wrong, but I don't see why. (Additionally, the same argument says that if this is $L:0\rightarrow 0$ then charge congugation $C$ is not a conserved quantity either.)

Comment: Working in the ZMF does not imply L=0.  The two momenta (incoming or outgoing) can be equal and opposite but with a transverse offset between them.

Comment: @RogerJBarlow so am I right that this can't happen if the collision is perfectly head on, but that just doesn't happen in practice (no phase space volume)?

Comment: @RogerJBarlow I think you're right, but I can't visualise this for the QM case where I have infinite extended plane waves impinging on each other from opposite directions. I feel like I shouldn't be needing to rely on specific wave packet shapes just to know if something is possible at all.

Comment: Thinking of such a collision like two trucks colliding head on is not helpful because of Heisenberg: $\Delta y$ is zero so $\Delta p_y$ is infinite.  Two extended plane waves moving in opposing directions and meeting is a much more valid way to think about it. Then you remember that a plane wave can be expressed as a sum of partial waves  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_wave_expansion. and so the plane wave collapses into a particular $L$ component.

Comment: you are forgetting the polarization of the photons. similar argument to https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/483588/why-are-physicists-so-worried-about-p-symmetry-violations-while-symmetry-is-alr#comment1086712_483588  . see link https://www.imsc.res.in/~taushif/pdfs/Intrinsic%20parity%20of%20neutral%20pion.pdf

Comment: @annav I'm not sure the polarizations have anything to do with it, parity doesn't depend on spin angular momentum. For a composite particle, the parity is the product of that of the substituents, times a factor of $(-1)^L$ to account for parity of the bound state spatial wavefunction $Y_l^m$.

Comment: @RogerJBarlow so in the partial wave picture they can collide with $L=1$ (thus $P=+1$) and produce a pair of photons with $L=0$ ($P=+1$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The electron-positron collision state in question has the *same* quantum numbers as   [positronium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positronium), which  may exist in two states. The first of these is the short-lived singlet state $^1S_0$, so $L=S=J=0$, hence $P=-$ and $C=(-)^{L+S}=+$, and this is your parapositronium two-photon mode (must have even number of photons, from *C*), with [symmetric parity-odd wavefunction](https://sites.fas.harvard.edu/~phys191r/References/b3/Harpen2004.pdf),
$$
\propto (|\hat \epsilon _1\rangle  |\hat \epsilon _2\rangle - |\hat \epsilon _2\rangle |\hat \epsilon _1\rangle)(e^{ik(\hat {\mathbf k} \cdot ({\mathbf r}_1- {\mathbf r}_2)-2t)}- e^{ik(\hat {\mathbf k} \cdot ({\mathbf r}_2- {\mathbf r}_1)-2t)}  )  , 
$$
for respective photon polarizations $\hat \epsilon_1, \hat\epsilon_2$.

Should remind you of the neutral pion (a pseudoscalar), and decays just like it into an odd-parity couple of photons.

The other, not sought here, long-lived  bound state is orthopositronium, triplet and longer lived, $^3S_1$, so $P=-, ~ C=-$. Hence, it must decay to 3γ, unless it were a virtual γ in production through collision of electron-positron.

(So, does this remind you of the  *ρ* or the *J/ψ* ?)

Comment: In the $L=0$ state is the parity not $-1$? Because the electron has $P=1$, the positron $P=-1$ (which way around is irrelevant obviously) and so the product has $P=-1$. This differs from the 2-photon decay products.

Comment: My question is not directly concerning $e^-e^+$ bound states but free particles that collide and annihilate. Perhaps if I understood the bound states that would answer my question though, although I think the issue might be my understanding of what $L$ means for incoming beams.

Comment: The odd-parity 2γ wavefunction is explicitly and simply given [here](https://sites.fas.harvard.edu/~phys191r/References/b3/Harpen2004.pdf).

Comment: Would you mind copying the odd-parity two photon wavefunction into the answer so I can accept it? My confusion was (at least in part) that I was assuming the two photon wavefunction needed to be even and so the process was parity violating. (The other issue was that I was forgetting partial wave expansions as noted in the comments to my OP.)

Comment: Done. I have taught neutral pion decay too many times for any sticking points to still stick...